# Will a Windows domain rename require new SIDs?

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-name, rename, active-directory

If I rename my local windows domain on my domain controller will all of the user accounts associated with the "old" domain name need to be recreated? Will the user SIDs still be valid and would my users login like normal with newdomain\username instead of olddomain\username and everything will be the way it was as if it never happened?

Comment: Not to get too much into your business, but given your past questions and the issues you seem to be running into, it ***really*** seems like you're well past the point where you should bring in outside help. Pay an Active Directory expert to unravel this mess of yours, and maybe even design and setup a new AD infrastructure *properly*.  I would never expect a forest to work properly and reliably after what your questions indicate you've put it through. It will only get harder and worse the longer you put it off, so bite the bullet now and save yourself a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: [Given the total disaster your last domain rename was](http://serverfault.com/q/657808/118258), you really want to try that again?  Yeesh. Setup a new domain, properly, and migrate everything off of this trainwreck.

Comment: I think you're right. Perhaps when I get some time I'll go virtual and run two servers off the same box so ePo and WSUS don't conflict too.

Comment: Judging by your previous questions, and the lack of a "I brought down our corporate domain" type response. Am I correct in thinking that this is your personal environment / a test environment? If so... Start over. You can't guarantee going forward that your issues aren't related to the troubles you've had with your domain. You're better of starting clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I rename my local windows domain on my domain controller will all
>   of the user accounts associated with the "old" domain name need to be
>   recreated?

No.

> Will the user SIDs still be valid ...

Yes.

> ... and would my users login like normal  with newdomain\username instead of olddomain\username and everything will be the way it was as if it never happened?

Users, yes. If you have applications that connect using stored credentials, rather than as services, you'll need to fix the connection strings/auth info to reference the new domain also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will still be valid. The computer will need two restart from memory and the domain name will change in the "login to" box.